In graph Contrast learning, the cosine similarity of graph-level embedding vectors is too high
As mentioned in the title, in a graph contrast learning task, the graph-level embedding cosine similarity obtained is almost 1. It has also appeared before that the embedding vector has unusually large values. What could be the problem and what should be done
The model structure is a traditional shared convolution plus independent multi-layer perceptron mode. The loss function is barlow twins loss, in which the multi-layer perceptron has a batch normal layer.

Maybe you could show the approach (code) you had for this task?

I have uploaded my code, please help to have a look.

Graph convolution layer：
class GraphEncoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_curve_dim: int, in_surface_dim: int, out_dim: int, layer_num=2):
    super().__init__()
    self.layer_num = layer_num
    self.node_conv_layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()
    self.edge_conv_layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()
    self.pool = SAGPooling(in_channels=out_dim)
    self.linear_cat_emb = Linear2ProjectEncoder(out_dim * (self.layer_num), out_dim)
    self.linear_cat_node_emb = Linear2ProjectEncoder(out_dim * 2, out_dim)
    for _ in range(self.layer_num):
        self.node_conv_layers.append(NodeConv(out_dim, out_dim))
        self.edge_conv_layers.append(EdgeConv(out_dim, out_dim))
    self.linears_prediction = torch.nn.ModuleList()
    self.linears_prediction.extend(
        [nn.Linear(out_dim, out_dim),
         nn.Linear(out_dim, out_dim),
         nn.Linear(out_dim, out_dim)]
    )
def forward(self, batch):
    x, edge_index, edge_attr, batch_index = batch.x, batch.edge_index, batch.edge_attr, batch.batch
    hidden_x = []
    hidden_e = []
    for i in range(self.layer_num):
        x = self.node_conv_layers[i](x, edge_index, edge_attr)
        hidden_x.append(x)
        edge_attr = self.edge_conv_layers[i](x, edge_index, edge_attr)
        hidden_e.append(edge_attr)
    node = hidden_x[-1]
    hidden_emb = []
    for i in range(len(hidden_x)):
        pool_x, _, _, pool_batch_index, _, _ = self.pool(hidden_x[i], edge_index, batch=batch_index)
        hidden_emb.append(global_max_pool(pool_x, pool_batch_index))
    emb = self.linear_cat_emb(torch.cat(hidden_emb, dim=1))
    extend_emb = emb[batch_index]
    node = self.linear_cat_node_emb(torch.cat((node, extend_emb), dim=1))
    return node, emb

loss funtion：
def barlow_twins_loss(z_a，z_b):
batch_size = z_a.size(0)
feature_dim = z_a.size(1)
_lambda = 1 / feature_dim

# Apply batch normalization
z_a_norm = (z_a - z_a.mean(dim=0)) / (z_a.std(dim=0) + EPS)
z_b_norm = (z_b - z_b.mean(dim=0)) / (z_b.std(dim=0) + EPS)

# Cross-correlation matrix
c = (z_a_norm.T @ z_b_norm) / batch_size

# Loss function
off_diagonal_mask = ~torch.eye(feature_dim).bool()
loss = (
        (1 - c.diagonal()).pow(2).sum()
        + _lambda * c[off_diagonal_mask].pow(2).sum()
)

return loss

